What is the genealogy of the Mrudah Clan?
I'm working on a project of the family tree and origins of the House of Saud, the ruling family of Saudi Arabia. According to Wikipedia, the last recorded ancestor of the House of Saud is Mani' ibn Rabi'a al Muraydi, but their geneaology can be tracked back further through tribal oral traditions. Supposedly, Mani' ibn Rabi'a al-Muraydi was a member of the Mrudah Clan who are descended from the Banu Hanifa tribe. Through this information I was able to collect information from the Internet to trace the House of Saud back to an ancient man named Adnan who was also the ancestor of the Islamic Prophet Muhammad, and thus many other great Islamic Dynasties. However, there is still a great gap between the Mrudah Clan and the Banu Hanifa. If anybody can give me more information on the genealogy of the Mrudah Clan I would very greatly appreciate it.

Did you check the source cited in the Wikipedia article you referenced? Regime stability in Saudia Arabia

First of all, there is no consensus on whether they were from the Banu Hanifah or their relatives in the Rabi'a, the Anizah. For me, the Anizah makes more sense, as Mani' had no former connections in the area, and came from the shore of Eastern Arabia. As well, the remnants of the Banu Hanifah are merged with the Anixah, so we can consider them of the Anizah.
Suppose the Mrudah was from the Anizah, who are more well-recorded. In that case, it is simple: the Anizah are recorded of having migrated into the area around that point, and they cover that whole distance between the 1400s AD and the before Muhammad (SAW) (Anizah b. Asad b. Rabia b. Mudar b. Nizar. b. Ma'ad b. Adnan min Bani Isma'il b. Ibrahim b. Azar aw Tarah). 
If we say that they were from the Hanifa, then it becomes more murky. However, ibn Battuta mentions that people in the region still identify with Bani Hanifah, and ibn Battuta lived around the same time as Mani' ibn Rabi. So it covers the whole distance between the 1400s AD and the before Muhammad (SAW) (Hanifa b. Lujaim b. Saab b. Ali b. Bakr b. Wa'il b. Qasit b. Hinb b. Afsa b. Dumi b. Jadila b. Asad b. Rabia b. Mudar b. Nizar. b. Ma'ad b. Adnan min Bani Isma'il b. Ibrahim b. Azar aw Tarah).
I believe that there might be information in the book "Nubdhah fi ansab Ahl Najd". I have no access to it, though.
Hope this helps.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
